# Triggering Specific jobs w.r.t changes done in specific folder in azure devops pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I have three folders named AutomationScript1, AutomationScript2, AutomationScript3. I have a pipeline for which I added a build policy such that whenever there is a pull request created. I'll have to manually trigger that pipeline.

But I have another requirement where if the pull request has changes to folder1 i need to run a set of code within the PowerShell script. if there are changes to folder2 then a set of code within the same task. If there are changes to both folder1 & 2, then I need to run both. I'm not able to detect the changes within those folders in the pull request.

I tried with the below code i added code such that it'll execute different jobs on the seeing the changes.

```
stages:
- stage: CheckChanges
  jobs:
  - job: CheckChanges
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $changes = git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only
          $aChanged = $changes -match "AutomationScripts1/"
          $bChanged = $changes -match "AutomationScripts2/"
          $cChanged = $changes -match "AutomationScripts3/"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=aChanged]$aChanged"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=bChanged]$bChanged"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=cChanged]$cChanged"

- stage: A
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), or(eq(variables['aChanged'], 'True'), and(ne(variables['aChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['bChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['cChanged'], 'True'))))
  jobs:
  - job: RunA
    steps:
    - script: echo "Running A"

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), or(eq(variables['bChanged'], 'True'), and(ne(variables['aChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['bChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['cChanged'], 'True'))))
  jobs:
  - job: RunB
    steps:
    - script: echo "Running B"

- stage: C
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), or(eq(variables['cChanged'], 'True'), and(ne(variables['aChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['bChanged'], 'True'), ne(variables['cChanged'], 'True'))))
  jobs:
  - job: RunC
    steps:
    - script: echo "Running C"
```

But i'm okay even if can achieve the same within one job as well.